# NodeJS(Loopback): loopback-connector-rest with multipart/form-data (FormData)

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, loopbackjs, form-data

I am trying to call a 3rd party API with loopback-connector-rest POST request (multipart/form-data), while I am creating a instance of form-data in the request body, and try to access it, It throws error from request package. How can I use formData. On passing formData inside the connector-template, it don't show. Where should I use form-data, in body or form?

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Method get TypedArray.prototype.length called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

NOTE: Reading a file from the container as buffer and adding to form data.